# Regarding to OCD about Reading Mathematical Books

Tags: self-learning, learning

Dear Math Stack Exchange advisers,

I recently started to develop an OCD-like symptom about reading books in mathematics.  Whenever I read previous pages and proceed to next, I always feel under a huge suspicion and fear that I did not understand and memorize the materials presented on those previous pages, which leads me to re-read those pages, doubt again, and re-read those pages words-to-words, and waste my time eventually.  I am sure this is not a normal behavior, and I would like to seek your advices and opinions about this anxiety coming from learning.

Somehow, I always under huge fear that I did not perfectly understand previous pages of book, even if I do understand for most parts, and under involuntary response of re-reading those pages.  I am quite frustrated about this action.

I need to stop that behavior as it demands a lot of time, but I simply cannot stop due to anxiety.

Comment: OCD is a medical diagnosis. It is not a synonym for "persnickety" or anything like that. If you really believe you might have OCD you should see a psychiatrist. If you just mean you are persnickety then well that's fairly common among mathematicians.

Comment: I think it is ridiculous to say you are anxious about reading maths when in the same time it seems you like to come on MSE.

Comment: These are classic signs of _learning_. But on a serious note, this is not the place to discuss whether or not you have a serious mental health issue.

Comment: This is obsessive, unhealthy, and unproductive. Deal with it as you would deal with any issue of obsessive thinking.

Comment: @user1952009  Why do you think so?  I visit MSE to resolve my confusion.

Comment: @user1952009 I don't think it's ridiculous at all.

Comment: @JairTaylor : most people here have the level for passing the secondary-school teaching diploma, i.e. for getting a good and pleasant job (not even mentioning the billions of jobs in engineering), so it is not as if their life was very difficult and pathetic.

Comment: @user1952009 I assume you have a habit of mocking other people, which is not good behavior in general.  I think your mode of thinking is quite pathetic.  I did not whine about my problem since I wanted to get some advice about behaviors from mathematicians.  I also do not see your point.  If you do want want to provide advice, then I suggest you to not bring your problem on other people.

Comment: I think it is rather normal, What you probably encounter is that you do not remember **exactly** the steps that were taken in the book in order to achieve a proof of some theorem or the solution of some example/exercise that were presented. What is really important is to understand the general concept/idea behind a proof or a solution to an exercise, And not to remember the "exact" steps that were shown in the book.

Comment: In the software industry, I encounter similar situations, I for example, do not remember **exactly** the **exact** steps/instructions that I’ve coded into the computer to achieve some solution to an algorithmic problem, Just waiting a week, And I will forget all those **little details**, But if I will encounter the problem again I will be able to resolve it,

Comment: What is really important is to understand the general idea behind a proof or a solution to a problem, And not those **exact steps** or **little details**, With the general idea in mind and enough experience with the matter, you will safely be able to reconstruct the proof/solution/algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a perfectly valid question. By no means I am a good mathematician/math learner, but here is what I think based on my own experience. Usually, if you doubt whether you have understood something or not, it is quite likely that you did not. For example, will you ever doubt that the solutions of $ax^2 + bx + c=0$ is given by $\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$? Probably not. Because you have solves quadratic equations for so many times. Even if somehow, you start doubting whether this is true or not, you can always verify that this indeed is true easily.

Things get a little bit trickier when you study more advanced math, for example, real analysis. My suggestion would be that, if you have enough time, it does not really hurt trying to redo/relearn the proofs that you did before but confuses you now. Notice that however if you have limited time then probably this is not the best idea.

To give you a concrete example, yesterday I was playing around with the following problem:

> Consider the function $f(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ when $x\ne 0 $ and $f(x)=k$ when $x=0$. For what $k$ is the graph of the function not connected?

This is a topology question. However,somehow I was reminded of the continuity of the function. I remember that this function is not continuous at $x=0$ because I did the exact same question when I was taking analysis. However, when I tried to redo the proof, I started confusing myself, which resulted in the following question:

[Negation of definition of continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857945/negation-of-definition-of-continuity)

Was it normal that I confused myself? It is hard to say. However, one thing is for sure. That is, I relearned something that I probably overlooked and now I have a better understanding of the subject, which is good. Going back to your question, what you are experiencing is normal. What should you do? Think it over and over until you are totally convinced. As long as you are learning, you are never wasting your time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice!  I agree with you that it is probably the case that i did not understand the concept if I doubt about my understanding.  Although I seem to focus little more on trivial stuffs, so I needed to get those out of my mind and focus on important concepts

Comment: @MathWanderer "Trivial" could be a dangerous word in a sense that it really depends on the person. For example, $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is a field might seem trivial to a professor but certainly not to someone just started learning algebra! If something does not seem trivial to you, then it is in fact _not trivial_ to you and you need to figure it out.